# Binomial theorem for non integers ? O_o ??

Tags: binomial-theorem

Could we use the binomial theorem for non integers? This comes from:

$$\sqrt{(a+b)}$$ which I can write as $$(a+b)^{1/2}$$

Could I then use the binomial theorem to figure out the value of this expression?

Comment: How would you do it? You can define a binomial for real coefficients, but will it make your life easier?

Comment: @user120820 Well I like the taste of hard life ;)

Comment: Then read this

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/12079/gamma-function-versions-of-combinatorial-identites

Comment: @LeoAzevedo Binomial theorem for real numbers is ultra useful for quick asymptotic expansions.

Comment: I always like a good challenge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes:
$$
(a+b)^{\frac{1}{2}}=a^{\frac{1}{2}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{k}\bigg(\frac{b}{a}\bigg)^k 
$$
EDIT: fractional binomial coefficients are calculated as the regulae ones. Just replace the fraction with, say, $\alpha$ and use the definition:
$$
\binom{\alpha}{k}=\alpha \cdot (\alpha-1) \cdots (\alpha-k+1) \cdot \frac{1}{k!}
$$
and then substitute the fraction. What do you get?

Comment: but What does this actually mean?

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: can you give me an example with $(1+1)^{1/2}$

Comment: Please see the edit

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28binomial%281%2F2%2Ck%29%2Ck%3D0...n%29

Comment: Here the sum converges to $2^\frac{1}{2}$ as $n \to \infty$

Comment: Thank you, you're very kind! :))

Answer (score 7):

The generalized binomial theorem is actually a special case of [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series), which states that

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k$$

Where $f^{(k)}(a)$ is the $k$th derivative centered at $a$. In particular if we have $f(x)=x^t$, note that

$$f'(x)=tx^{t-1}\\f''(x)=t(t-1)x^{t-2}\\\vdots\\f^{(k)}(x)=t(t-1)(t-2)\dots(t-k+1)x^{t-k}$$

Let $x=a+b$ and we find that

$$f(x)=(a+b)^t=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{t(t-1)\dots(t-k+1)}{k!}a^{t-k}b^k$$

which is the generalized binomial expansion theorem! Special case of $t=-1,-2$ are interesting, as it gives

$$(1-x)^{-1}=1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots\\(1-x)^{-2}=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+\dots$$

Answer (score 4):

You can see the following link, that explanes what occurs when the exponent is a complex number: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

Answer (score 2):

The Binomial Theorem says
$$
\begin{align}
(1+x)^{1/2}
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{1/2}{k}x^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2k-1}\binom{2k}{k}\left(\frac{x}4\right)^k\\
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, if $|a|\le b$,
$$
(a+b)^{1/2}=b^{1/2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2k-1}\binom{2k}{k}\left(\frac{a}{4b}\right)^k
$$